# Как скопировать файл с помощью symlink?

Tags: symlinks, sys

Начала учиться на сисадмина. Дано дз по работе с командной строкой. Надо было создать файл в директории, потом создать на него ссылку.
Теперь же мне надо этот мой файл скопировать в мною созданный каталог, используя эту ссылку.
Вот дословное задание:

***Создайте ссылку в /opt на созданный вами в предыдущем задании каталог.
Используя созданную ссылку, скопируйте concept.1 в тот же каталог, назвав concept.1.old.
Приведите команды, которыми вы это сделали.
Удалите оригинальный файл. Выведите на экран содержимое созданного вами каталога.***
(concept.1 это файл, находящийся в созданном мною каталоге.)

Ссылку я создала символическую. Надеюсь, хоть это верно получилось.)

Помогите, пожалуйста. Уже весь интернет обрыла, ничего не нашла.
Можно ли в данном случае использовать cp? Если да, то как. Нужно сначала ссылку открыть и потом копировать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать `cp`. Как обычно. Из любого места. Особенность будет в последнем пункте вопроса если использовать опции `-L` и/или `-l`.

Просто выполните задание на компьютере и запишите результат... суть лабораторной работы в том чтоб попробовать.

Answer (score 0):

Отрезолвить симлинк можно командой `realpath`:

```
realpath ./link_name
```

Если вы будете копировать просто указывая симлинк, шелл так и скопирует симлинк без копирования объекта, на который он указывает.

Полная правильная команда будет:

```
cp -r $(realpath ./link_name) ./destination
```